# cout prints inaccurate result and printf prints accurate result

Tags: c++, printf, double, cout

The following code in C++:

```cpp
    double x = 500000.6;
    printf("%f\n", x);
    cout << x << endl;
```

prints the following:

```
500000.600000
500001
```

Why `cout` isn't printing the correct value (500000.6)?

Putting the following line as the beginning of the code makes `cout` prints correct result:

```cpp
cout.precision(7);
```

However, setting the precision to 6 (which is the default anyways) doesn't print the expected result.

Why this happen? I have only **1 digit** after the decimal point, not **7 digits**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the precision is the total number of significant digits. It's not the number of digits after the decimal point. `500000.6` has seven significant digits, `500001` has only six.

Try this instead

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << x << endl;
```

When used for *fixed format*, the precision is the number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Great! It works. I just have a small question, what is "fixed"? it's not a function, because no parentheses follows it. Then, what it is? cout is used for printing, but `cout << fixed` just changes cout behavior without printing anything. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: It's called a manipulator, `endl` and `setprecision` are also manipulators.`fixed` actually is the name of a function. The function is passed to operator<< as a function pointer and called by operator<<. See here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip